# Javascript function doesn't called from codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript

I have function in javascript with argument and I want to call this function multiple times when Gridview bind its data. so I have put the code like this

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem) != null)
 {
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),new Random().Next(100).ToString(), 
                        "likeStatus('"+argument+"')", true);
 }
}
```

Each time I change the value of `key` but this function is called only once.
so please help me what should I do to call function in each iteration of gridview binding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: make the key dynamic, so that each script in page is registered with a unique id,  it shall then be called. Registering with the same key prohibits multiple script registrations.

Comment: I have also used random key but it doesn't work

Comment: Please use Unique key everytime...@BrijeshGandhi

Comment: Mr.Vishal have u not seen I have already told that I am using random key

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you need randomness you need to use the same instance of `Random` and can't create a new one each time. The way you are doing it right now might generate the same value every time. (Also note that a random value is not the same as a unique value)
To solve the problem I would however do thing a little differently.

Declare a `StringBuilder` as a field in you class. Create it before you bind the grid:

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
gridView.DataBind();
```

Then in the `RowDataBound` event of the `GridView` write to the builder.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem) != null)
       sb.Append("likeStatus('"+argument+"');");
}
```

Finally in `PreRender` register the script string

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", 
                        sb.ToString(), true);
```

Alternatively use a unique value as the key, for example `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`